# SKSpriteNode using PDF/SVG Vector Image for automatic scaling

Tags: ios, swift, vector, sprite-kit, xcode9

I'm trying to use a PDF/SVG Image as the SKTexture for an SKSpriteNode.
I know that this can be done for a UIImageView by ticking "Preserve Vector Data", setting Scaled to "Single Scale" and configuring the UIImageView to

```
imageView.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true
```

Is this possible to do when using the UIImage in an SKTexture? This would prevent the creation of @2x & @3x images.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

### You cannot use vector images for an SKTexture

A `SKTexture` doesn't have a vector format, it's simply a bitmap image.

So when you add a `PDF` vector image to your asset catalog and then you create a `SKTexture` out of it, you get a bitmap image (also if you selected `Preserve Vector Format` and `Single scale`)

The good part of this procedure is that you don't need to create the 1x, 2x and 3x sized images since Xcode will do it for you at build time. But the generated texture is still going to be in bitmap format.