# "Error loading image resource' from xcasset using PDF

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have an "Arrows.xcassets" containing two items, both PDFs of vector art arrows. They are set to "Scales->Single Scale" and loaded into the Universal slot.

I am trying to load them into an SKNode:

```
let arrowTex = SKTexture(imageNamed:"green_arrow_up")
let up = SKSpriteNode(texture: arrowTex))
```

When I run this, I get this error in the console:

```
Error loading image resource: "green_arrow_up"
```

There are a number of posts hinting that this is something you can do (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078362/skspritenode-using-pdf-svg-vector-image-for-automatic-scaling) one), but I can't find one that actually shows how to refer to the images in question. I tried:

```
green_arrow_up@1x
green_arrow_up@1x.png
green_arrow_up
green_arrow_up.png
```

but none of those worked. I'm sure there's a simple trick?

**UPDATE:** I found a second thread of the linked question which had more details including a link to a known-good file. I grabbed that file and it worked fine, I was even able to scale it down nice and small and it still looks great. I used Gapplin for the conversion from SVG to PDF, does anyone know one that works?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some poking about I found a solution. Gappin simply doesn't do the conversion correctly, although what that means I can't really say. However, I found an [online converter](https://convertio.co/svg-pdf/), and presto, everything works. So if you get this error, try using that converter and see if that fixes it.